# Redundant direct object pronoun

Tags: pronouns

I have heard the following rhetorical question in a movie:

> Lo sai che l'avvocato è l'unico che può farti uscire?

The direct object "lo" seems redundant to me, as the sentence "che l'avvocato è..." works as the object of "sapere" in this sentence. Is that gramatically correct and usual?

Comment: This is an example of what is called "dislocazione a destra": a complement which comes after a sentence ("lo sai" in your example) and which is anticipated in this sentence by a pronoun ("lo" in your example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see at [Treccani Encyclopedia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dislocazioni_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), which gives an example very similar to your sentence (see example number (55))

> Lo sai che Gianluca sta male?

this kind of construction is what is called "dislocazione a destra". It consists of a complement which comes after a complete sentence ("lo sai" in your example) and which is anticipated in this sentence by a pronoun ("lo" in your example). In words by Vittorio Coletti in his book *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto*:

> Il costrutto sbilanciato a sinistra ha una sua variante simmetricamente opposta a destra della frase detta o scritta: il complemento, che di per sé già viene dopo soggetto e verbo, può essere ritardato ulteriormente dopo l'intera frase che lo anticipa solo tramite un pronome (dislocazione a destra): «l'ho letto, il libro», «non ci sono andato, a Venezia», «gliel'ho subito detto, a Mario».

In this same book, Coletti explains that this kind of constructions are typical and very frequent in oral speech, but are also becoming increasingly common in writing of medium formality:

> Sono strategie, come si vede, proprie del dialogo, del parlato, ma sempre più comuni nello scritto medio. In una scheda di presentazione della riproposizione, nel 1997, di un celebre film di Fritz Lang, si legge: «Lang propone Frank come un personaggio che, sopraffatto dalle circostanze, è costretto a diventare un eroe a suo modo, e anche un'analisi della mitologia del West, in cui spesso la giustizia la fa il cittadino e non la legge»; un testo abbastanza formale, colto, adopera con tranquillità un costrutto orale come la dislocazione a sinistra («la giustizia la fa il cittadino»), tanto questa è ormai consueta nella prosa media, per non dire, ovviamente, quanto è comune nei romanzi e, in essi, nei discorsi diretti dei personaggi. Una frase come «il giornale oggi i giovani non lo comprano più» è assolutamente plausibile anche in uno scritto. E neppure la dislocazione a destra, frequentissima nel parlato, «me lo faresti un piacere?» (si ricordi Renzo nei *Promessi Sposi*: «la farò io la giustizia: lo libererò io, il paese»), manca nello scritto divulgativo o comunque di media o bassa formalità, ed è frequente nei romanzi.

So, about your question if that is correct, you should avoid it if you are writing a very formal text but, as Coletti says, otherwise you can use it without any problem.