# Which is the meaning of 'ci' on this context: "Che ci fai qui?"

Tags: word-usage, particles

I don't understand the meaning of 'ci' when a person say: "Che ci fai qui?". It seems redundant the use of 'ci' and then the use of 'qui'.

Comment: In a comment to [this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11116/ce-li-hai-gli-occhi-pronouns) I am listing other questions about _ci_. I am not saying this is a duplicate. Would you like to have a look at those questions and see whether any of them answers your question?

Comment: On a related but distinct note: sooner or later, someone should write (or transcribe from some text) the ultimate answer about _ci_, and make it the Über-FAQ.

Comment: @DaG great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence, "ci" has the meaning of "in questo luogo" or "qui". It is used in a pleonastic way because the sentence in your question contains a "dislocazione a destra", a construction typical of oral speech which is explained in detail in [this answer](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10864).

Your sentence has indeed a similar structure to this example

> Non ci sono andato, a Venezia

given in the book *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* by Vittorio Coletti: there is a place complement ("a Venezia" in Coletti's example, "qui" in your sentence) that goes after a complete clause and which is anticipated in this clause by particle "ci". Another example with the same phenomenon is explained in the answers to [this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11038).