# Di tempo ormai ce n'è poco

Tags: meaning, difference

I have heard the following line in a TV series:

> Di tempo ormai ce n'è poco

The translation in the English subtitle was "Time is running out". Is there any difference in meaning between it and "il tempo ormai sta finendo" ? Why is "ne" used here?

Comment: «the "non" in this sentence»: which “non”? Should you refer to “n'”, that's an elision for “ne”.

Comment: @DaG Sure, I got confused here. I'll remove that from the original question, as it is not relevant.

Comment: Thanks, Alan. This kind of redundancy falls within the general phenomenon of _dislocazioni_ explained by @Charo [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/redundant-direct-object-pronoun/10864#10864).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence you have heard is an example of what is called ["dislocazione a sinistra"](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dislocazioni_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/): it consists of a complement ("di tempo") which is written at the beginning of a sentence and then repeated in the sentence in the form of a clitic pronoun ("ne").

In his book *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto*, Vittorio Coletti explains the reasons why this kind of construction is used in oral speech and in informal written Italian:

> L'italiano è una lingua che trasmette le informazioni linearmente; le novità vengono dopo le cose note; il soggetto  (noto) è seguito dal predicato e dai suoi eventuali complimenti  (nuovo). Se dico «Mario mangia la mela», chi mi ascolta sa chi è Mario, ma non cosa fa e e glielo dico io: «mangia la mela». 
>       Nel passaggio dal latino all'italiano e alle altre lingue romanze l'ordine delle parole è diventato uno strumento per identificarne il ruolo, ed è quindi importante; basti pensare a una frase come «Mario ama Maria» in cui il soggetto è identificato solo dalla posizione (a volte col concorso del senso, come in «il cane morde il padrone»). Ma questo comportamento sintattico può non essere rispettato per ragioni comunicative  (testuali) e il modo con cui si fornisce l'informazione può allora entrare in conflitto con quello della sintassi standard. Ad esempio, se l'informazione che debbo dare riguarda cosa fa il noto Mario dirò: «Mario canta», ma se riguarda chi canta dirò: «canta Mario», posticipando il soggetto perché è lui la novità dell'informazione. Dunque la regola che prevede il soggetto prima del verbo è sospesa infinite volte e con certi verbi molto frequentemente («suonano le campane», «c'è qualcuno alla porta», «arriva il treno»). Capita anche di sospendere persino la regola che vuole il complemento in fondo: «Mario mangia la mela»; se voglio dare contrastivamente rilievo al complemento «la mela» (qualcuno mi ha chiesto se Mario mangia la pera) dirò: «la mela, Mario mangia», sottinteso, grazie all'intonazione e all'ordine delle parole, «non la pera». Se quello che viene di regola dopo lo metto prima, la novità della posizione diventa anche quella dell'informazione (in contrasto con la regola della successione dal noto al nuovo). 
>       Me se mi si chiede chi ha mangiato la mela, che è quindi per me un dato ormai noto, poso rispondere dicendo: «la mela, l'ha mangiata Mario», anticipando il complemento, riprendendolo con un pronome e a seguire verbo e soggetto, perché il soggetto è la novità della mia informazione. Rispondendo in questo modo, ho mantenuto il contatto con l'oggetto della domanda (la mela) e ho dato rilievo alla mia risposta anticipando nella posizione del noto  una funzione sintattica  (il complemento) che in genere occupa quella (posteriore) del nuovo.

> Ho così usato un costrutto tipico del parlato e dello scritto informale o che simula il parlato, risalente addirittura alle origini della nostra lingua: si trova infatti già nel Placito Capuano del 960, nelle dichiarazioni dei testimoni (lingua dunque parlata, ancorché formulare, rituale in un processo). Paolo D'Achille ha mostrato l'antichità e la continuità nel tempo di costrutti come questo, anche negli usi scritti, e Sabatini li ha classificati fra i tratti riemersi con evidenza nella grammatica del nuovo italiano dell'«uso medio» per via del maggior uso parlato della lingua, riammessi anche alla scrittura più nobile dall'impiego che ne fa Manzoni nei *Promessi Sposi*. 
>       Qualsiasi complemento può essere dislocato (il costrutto è detto dislocazione a sinistra) in questo modo e poi ripreso con un pronome: «a Venezia ci andrò la prossima settimana», «a Mario non glielo dico».

That is, one of the functions of this "dislocazione a sinistra" construction is to change the "standard" order of words in a sentence so that the ones that come at the end are perceived by the listener as a new information. The sentence you have heard is constructed that way (instead of "c'è poco tempo") because the listener probably knows they are speaking about time or that there is time involved in something, but the new (unknown by the listener) fact the speaker wants to express is that the amount of remaining time is small.

Comment: Regarding "ma se riguarda chi canta dirò: «canta Mario»", could you give an example of dialogue where it would be said? The first attempt that comes to my head is: - Chi canta questa canzione? - Mario", but the person answering the question would usually not repeat "canta" here.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: I can imagine a situation in which two people are going to a concert. They know that there will be a song, but they don't know who is the singer. One of them begins to read the concert program and says to the other: "Canta Mario Rossi".

Comment: Thanks for the example! As there is a direct object, shouldn't your example be "La canta Mario Rossi" ? My challenge in understanding this subject-predicate inversion is identifying the contexts in which they would be used because English would simply express the emphasis differently (only in spoken language). For instance, your last example would usually be expressed in English as "*Mario Rossi* will/is going to sing this one" or "*Mario Rossi* is the singer of this one" if they are discussing about the song (the singer name is italicized to express emphasis while speaking).

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but "c'è/ho poco tempo" is way more usual than "il tempo sta finendo".
As explained by DaG there's no "non" in this sentence so I don't get the first question.
Building the phrase this way with a redundant "ne" [(pronome di ripresa)](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-di-ripresa_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), put even more attention on the word "tempo" and is likely to be used if it was already mentioned in the conversation. Maybe this phrase is the answer to something like "ci serve più tempo" or "ci vorrà molto tempo"?

Comment: I got confused between "non" and "ne". I have fixed the question. Regarding the usage of "ne" and context, the sentence is not an answer to a question, it is just the beginning of a bigger statement: "Di tempo ormai ce n'è poco e senza il Monsegnori non lo so se avremo i voti necessari"

Comment: Is the preposition "di" gramatically required in "di tempo c'è poco" or just idiomatic?