# Alternativa ammissibile a "sta essendo" passivo

Tags: verbs, phrase-request, tenses

Mi è venuta in mente questa frase in un contesto correlato al lavoro

> Qualcuno sta essendo maltrattato dai dirigenti

ma poi ho avuto il dubbio che se potesse veramente usare la locuzione "sta essendo" in italiano. Mi riferisco a qualcuno che soffre delle ingiustizie da parte dei dirigenti nel contesto del lavoro.

Mi sono messa a ricercare e ho trovato questo [articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/strutture-perifrastiche_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) in cui si parla, tra altre cose, delle perifrasi di tipo "stare" + gerundio:

> *stare* + gerundio esprime tipicamente il valore progressivo

Ecco la spiegazione di quello che significa "valore progressivo":

> Una perifrasi ha valore progressivo quando un processo verbale iniziato precedentemente è colto in un singolo istante del suo svolgimento; in altre parole, è contrassegnato da una focalizzazione puntuale. Nel caso più tipico, il valore progressivo di una costruzione è reso dal cosiddetto *schema di incidenza* (Durante 1981: 181); vale a dire, dall’accostamento di una frase con un verbo di aspetto perfettivo e azione non durativa, e una frase con un verbo di aspetto imperfettivo e azione generalmente durativa, come nell’esempio seguente: 
>   
>   
>   (1) quando hai suonato il campanello stavo guardando la televisione

Ma un po' più avanti, si indica:

> Nell’italiano contemporaneo *stare* + gerundio ha in realtà una sensibile espansione dei valori aspettuali, mostrandosi limitatamente compatibile anche con contesti durativi di carattere semelfattivo, purché il quadro di riferimento temporale non abbia durata determinata (per es., **stava leggendo per tre ore*) o struttura ‘densa’ (Bertinetto 1997: 168; per es., **stava leggendo istante dopo istante*): può infatti occorrere anche con avverbi di durata e di grado, come negli esempi seguenti (cfr. § 4): 
>   
>   
>   (4) il manoscritto a cui il professor Eco sta lavorando da due anni (da Squartini 1990: 193) 
>   
>   
>   (5) l’uso del laser ad argon si sta rivelando sempre più indispensabile (da Squartini 1990: 199) 
>   
>   
>   Decisamente marcati, e tendenzialmente non ammessi, risultano invece gli usi attestati in contesti durativi con valore abituale: 
>   
>   
>   (6) sto andando tutti i giorni a parlare alla signora (da Bertinetto 1997: 237)

La conclusione sarebbe che "stare" + gerundio si può effettivamente adoperare in alcuni costrutti, anche se, a quanto pare, l'ultimo caso spiegato non è tanto accettato.

Dopodiché, appare questa spiegazione in cui si trovano usi non ammessi di "sta essendo" e altre perifrasi del tipo "stare" + gerundio:

> *Stare* + gerundio mostra poi alcune restrizioni di carattere semantico e morfologico. Tra le prime si possono menzionare l’incompatibilità con i verbi stativi (per es., **sta essendo vecchio*, *sta stando in piedi*; ➔ [verbi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)), salvo che questi siano usati in senso non-stativo (per es., *sta avendo successo*); l'assunzione di valore imminenziale («stare per») se impiegata con un telico non durativo come verbo principale (ossia con un verbo che denota un evento che si conclude e che è pressoché istantaneo: per es., *sto partendo* «sto per partire»); la refrattarietà a essere retta da verbi modali (per es., **doveva stargli raccontando una storia* ➔ [modali, verbi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-modali_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)). Tra le seconde: l’incompatibilità con il passivo (per es., **l'automobile sta essendo riparata*); i tempi perfettivi (**è stato camminando*) i modi imperativo (per es., **sta' leggendo!*) e, tendenzialmente, infinito (**spero di non stare finendo*).

Quindi, se ho capito bene, non posso dire "sta essendo maltrattato" perché le perifrasi del tipo "stare" + gerundio sono incompatibili con la forma passiva. Allora, la mia domanda sarebbe: come potrei esprimere in un modo ammissibile la frase che ho scritto all'inizio del post, per trasmettere l'idea di qualcosa che si sta svolgendo nel momento presente e che dura nel tempo (preferibilmente con "dirigenti" posto alla fine della frase per le ragioni spiegate in [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11152/))?

Comment: Alternative: "sta venendo maltrattato dai dirigenti"; "sta subendo un maltrattamento dai dirigenti"; "i dirigenti lo stanno maltrattando"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ma "sta venendo maltrattato dai dirigenti" non è anche forma passiva?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi:  Hai ragione: la soluzione più semplice sarebbe trasformare la frase alla forma attiva, ma cambiando l'ordine dei diversi componenti della frase, si perdono sfumature su quale informazione si vuole trasmettere come un fatto nuovo (perlomeno nell'orale).

Comment: \**metti un backslash \ prima dell'asterisco (il primo)*

Comment: Grazie, @FedericoPoloni!

Comment: "Sta venendo maltrattato” si trova, pur se non in contesti “colti”. Credo che ci sia sotto l'influenza di “is being harassed”.

Comment: @Charo hai ragione, ho fatto qualche ricerca e in effetti la forma "sta venendo" + participio passato non sarebbe da considerare corretta (cfr. https://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=6102) però come scritto nello stesso thread, ha una certa diffusione.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi:  Ho stato cercando frasi con "sta subendo" su Google Libri. Potrebbe anche essere "Qualcuno sta subendo maltrattamento da parte dei dirigenti"?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi e Charo: A parte il discorso della forma con il gerundio, trovo che ci sia una differenza fra “essere/venire maltrattato” e “subire un maltrattamento”. Il primo può riferirsi anche a generiche ingiustizie, mentre il secondo mi dà quasi l'idea che lo picchino.

Comment: Sì, @DaG: io mi riferivo a soffrire delle ingiustizie. Ho aggiornato la domanda.

Comment: Lo immaginavo, @Charo: osservavo solo che “subire un maltrattamento” mi fa pensare soprattutto (anche se non esclusivamente) a qualcosa di più fisico.

Comment: @DaG: Allora forse sarebbe meglio   "Qualcuno sta subendo delle ingiustizie da parte dei dirigenti"?

Comment: "Sta subendo un trattamento discriminatorio", così forse non diamo l'impressione che lo menino ;)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Forse "sta subendo un trattamento ingiusto da parte dei dirigenti"? Come idea generale, cercare di usare "sta subendo" invece di "sta essendo" mi sembra una buona idea, solo che a volte si devono ricercare le parole giuste da mettere dopo questa espressione.

Comment: Non dico che funzioni sempre, dipende dalla frase. A volte, la soluzione può essere usare la forma impersonale: "*L'automobile sta essendo riparata" --> "L'automobile si sta riparando". "*Il pranzo sta essendo servito di sotto" (esempio tratto da [qui](http://tesi.cab.unipd.it/52392/1/MARTINA_BARATELLA_2016.pdf)) --> "Il pranzo si sta servendo di sotto".

Comment: "L'automobile si sta riparando" non mi sembra molto buono, dà l'impressione che si stia riparando da sola - almeno per me.

Comment: Confermo, @RiccardoDeContardi, anche per me qui l'impersonale si confonde con il riflessivo. Semmai una forma come “Stanno riparando l'automobile”.

Comment: Ah! Capisco, @DaG: grazie!