# Sono già passati quarant'anni vs Quarant'anni sono già passati - subject-verb vs verb-subject

Tags: word-order

Is there any difference in meaning and usage between subject-verb order and verb-subject order in Italian? Examples:

- "Quarant'anni sono già passati" vs "Sono già passati quarant'anni"
- "Tre ore sono già passate" vs "Sono già passate tre ore"

It seems to me that both orders mean the same, but the verb-subject order is more usual with the passing of time periods *in Italian* (unlike English).

Comment: yes, @alan they have the same meaning, the latter one is the most used in common speach.

Comment: @ChristianL.: Actually, they haven't the same meaning. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: The first phrasings are so unidiomatic to be ungrammatical, unless specifically meant for a reason.

More precisely, we have here a construction with a so-called [“unaccusative” verb](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-inaccusativi_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/). You can see more about them in the linked article, but the gist is that in Italian there are two classes of intransitive verbs, the “unergative” ones, where the subject is an actual subject (*lavorare*, *camminare*, *ridere*, *dormire*...) and the “unaccusative” ones, where the grammatical subject is a person or object to which something just happens, so to say (*arrivare*, *cadere*, *scoppiare*, *sparire*...).

Among the tests to distinguish them, there is the auxiliary verb used: *avere* for the unergative verbs (*Mario ha dormito*), *essere* for unaccusative ones (*Mario è arrivato*).

This said, one of the properties of unaccusative verbs is that they

> hanno il soggetto dopo il verbo in costruzioni non marcate, come si osserva in (5) a.-c. ..., proprietà generalmente non condivisa dal soggetto dei verbi inergativi (5 d.):
> (5) a. sono arrivati i libri
> b. sono partiti tutti
> c. è morto il bisnonno
> d. * hanno dormito i bambini

that is, unless we are explicitly, almost emphatically, talking about the books, everybody, or the great-grandfather, the usual construction is the one with the subject after the verb.

So, in our examples, the phrasing “*Quarant'anni sono già passati*” would be used if *quarant'anni* were our actual topic. Say, I'm saying that forty years would be a nice interval to wait for something, and you interject: “*Quarant'anni sono già passati*”. But in almost any other context, by far the most usual phrasing is “*Sono già passati quarant'anni*”.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, the meaning is *exactly the same*, the difference is the focus and usage. Isn't that right?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: Personally I wouldn't say so, but it all depends on what we mean by “meaning.” _Sono passati 40 anni_ means “Forty years have elapsed,” while _40 anni sono passati_ means, more or less, “Talking about 40 years, that's what's elapsed.” I'd call those two different meanings. It all has to do with the distinction between _tema_ (topic) and _rema_ (what's being said of the topic) in Italian; see https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/struttura-tematica_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/

Comment: @AlanEvangelista:  I think this has also to do with what is explained in [this answer](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11152/).

Comment: In this case, the word order perceived as neutral would be "Sono già passate tre ore". But if you have been talking with someone about "tre ore" so that this piece of information is already known by your interlocutor, let's say, for instance, your interlocutor has said "Abbiamo appena mangiato, quindi  dobbiamo aspettare almeno tre ore per poter andare a fare un bagno", and the news you want to transmit is "sono già passate" (e.g., because your interlocutor has been sleeping for hours and didn't realize how time passed), then you could say "Tre ore sono già passate".

Comment: So, I agree with DaG that there are some different nuances in meaning.

Comment: @DaG In the unaccusative example "Mario è arrivato", shouldn't the word order be inverted (i.e. È arrivato Mario) ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: Both are grammatical, it all depends about what we are actually meaning, what is our topic and what is the part said _about_ the topic: are we saying something about Mario or about people arriving? Compare “– Sono sicuro che Mario si farà aspettare. – Guarda che Mario è arrivato” with “– Ho sentito che hanno suonato... – Sì, è arrivato Mario”. Both are quite plausible.